# How can I find out how a Kubernetes Cluster was provisioned?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to determine how a Kubernetes cluster was provisioned. (Either using minikube, kops, k3s, kind or kubeadm).

I have looked at config files to establish this distinction but didn't find any.

Is there some way one can identify what was used to provision a Kubernetes cluster?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually but not always you can view the cluster(s) definition in your `~/.kube/config` and you will see "entry" per cluster usually with the type.

Again it's not 100%.

Another option is to check the pods & ns, if you will see minikube it is almost certain minikube, k3s, rancher etc.

[image]

If you will see namespace *cattle - it can be rancher with a k3s or with RKE

To summarize it, there is no single answer to how to figure out how your cluster was deployed, but you can find hints for that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see kubeadm configmap object in kube-system namespace then it means that the cluster is provisioned using kubeadm.

[image]